# Is it possible to access a routers admin settings from a remote server?

Tags: web, networking, admin, router, headless

Changing my home router settings from a remote server. Is this possible and if so any recommendations on how to go about it?

Haven't tried anything properly yet but have considered the idea of using js to get the client to open a headless browser, open 192.168.1.1, enter admin password and change needed settings.

Or is it possible to do it from the server side? Building the project in django (python) so would be much easier if I could open a connection between the clients router page and my server.

Comment: Try to look for `Remote Management` in the router menu - this will allow you to connect to the router from "outside network"

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I'm ideally wanting to get this working with routers like the BT Home Hub. They don't provide any inbuilt Remote Management.

Comment: You can try to do `Port Forwarding` from the "outside" to your router's address on port 80... it might work